# Android abrir apenas certos links no WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if (url.contains("https://m.sendspace.com/") || (url.contains("https://www.mediafire.com/file/") )) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex

                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            mWebView.stopLoading();


            return false;
    }
```

Os links listados lá são abertos no próprio aplicativo, já se o usuário solicitar um link que não está lá, abrirá no navegador. Isso funciona ok!
Agora meu problema é, links do Mediafire tem números de identificação diferentes exemplo: download1856.mediafire.com, download2536.mediafire.com...
Como faço para que esses links também abrem no próprio aplicativo?

Comment: Você tem um linke desses ai completo? O que acontece quando você tenta abrir esse link no browser?

Comment: Abre no navegador padrão. O link http://download1235.mediafire.com/t8nb1328qtcg/ehq80ly9q3gdcyz/Simple+Trolls.mcpack (Exemplo)

Comment: Mas esse link seria um arquivo, no entanto em vez de abrir uma página, você precisa criar uma programação para fazer download do arquivo. Seria isso mesmo?:

Comment: Sim, já tem o download manager, porém como se trata de diversos links do Mediafire eles tem a primeira numeração diferente. Ou seja pede para abrir no navegador :-(

Comment: Se o conteúdo do link varia mas a estrutura se mantêm constante use a estrutura para os identificar.

Comment: Como fazer isso?

Comment: Pessoal, eu consegui, porém as vezes abre no navegador, isso atrapalha muito! O que eu faço??